# PySide: pyside-uic preview of stylesheet css is different from actual display in app

Tags: css, qt, pyside, preview, qwidget

I've designed a mainwindow.ui in Qt Designer(4.8.2) in Microsoft Windows Vista, after previewing and being satisfied by the result then I used pyside-uic and got the generated mainwindow.py.
But when I run my app, the display is different from what I saw in the **Qt Designer preview** and is different from preview from the **pyside-uic --preview**:

What I used to get the preview:

```
pyside-uic mainwindow.py -p
```

The **init** of my app:

```
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
import sys

class bookcalendar(Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(bookcalendar, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = bookcalendar()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

what I saw running pyside-uic -p script,

[image]

what I saw running .py file,

[image]

```
stackedWidget(parent)

--bookStack      <-     my style sheet css

--calendarStack      <-     my style sheet css
```

css of the missing gray border:

```
#bookStack{
    "border: 3px solid gray;
    "background-color: white;}
```

Well, any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I found the answer myself.

Comment: What I did, is simply cut the css stylesheet on the bookStack to the css stylesheet on the parent , in my case, stackedWidget. Also edit specification to stackedWidget, and then, all the children stacks appear the same look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the workaround is to add the style sheet css in the parent, like:

```
stackedWidget(parent)      <-     style sheet css

--bookStack

--calendarStack
```

the right way to do css stylesheet:

```
#stackedWidget{
    "border: 3px solid gray;
    "background-color: white;}
```